# json converter only takes last key value for last dictionary instead of all

Tags: python, json, converters

Ok so I have the following list of dictionarys that I am trying to convert to a json file:

```
geojson_list = [

{'name': 'Parallelogram1', 'coordinates':
 [[115.67097179583487, -32.36672530921233], [115.96656222999665,
 -32.36672530921233], [115.90410905434761, -32.49580085924758], [115.60851862018583, -32.49580085924758], [115.67097179583487,
 -32.36672530921233]], 'area': 0.0381534978746},

{'name': 'Parallelogram2', 'coordinates': [[116.00622565359758,
 -32.5791364092627], [116.02283522420637, -32.5791364092627], [116.02126260408991, -32.59706839673082], [116.00465303348112,
 -32.59706839673082], [116.00622565359758, -32.5791364092627]],'area': 0.000297842612008}

]
```

This is the converter code named GeojsonConverter.py:

```
import json


def convert_to_geojson(my_list):
    """
    This function converts a list of dictionaries into GeoJSON format
    The dictionaries require a "coordinates" key whose value will be a 2D
    list, a "name" key, with all other additional data.
    :param my_list: A list of dictionaries
    :return: a GeoJSON string
    """

    try:
        for d in my_list:
            coord_list = d["coordinates"]
            name = d["name"]
            for coord in coord_list:
                float(coord[0])
                float(coord[1])

    except ValueError:
        print "ValueError: Coordinate cannot be converted to float."
        return "ValueError: Coordinate cannot be converted to float."

    except KeyError:
        print "KeyError: No 'coordinates' or 'name' key found in dictionary"
        return "KeyError: No 'coordinates' or 'name' key found in dictionary"

    except Exception as e:
        raise e

    else:
        feature_list = []
        property_dict = {}

        for d in my_list:
            coord_list = d["coordinates"]
            coord_list.append(d["coordinates"][0])
            name = d["name"]

            for key in d:
                if (key is not "name") and (key is not "coordinates"):
                    property_dict[key] = d[key]

            the_geom = {"type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [[coord_list]]}
            feature = {"type": "Feature", "geometry": the_geom, "name": name, "properties": property_dict}
            feature_list.append(feature)

        feature_collection = {"type": "FeatureCollection", "features": feature_list}

        return json.dumps(feature_collection)
```

The converter converts the list just fine right up until the area key. I keep getting the last value in area of the last dictionary for all dictionary areas, so in this case all areas = 0.000297842612008

This is the json file I get after running the list through the converter and writing it to a file:

```
 { "type": "FeatureCollection", "features": [{"geometry": {"type":
 "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [[[[115.67097179583487,
 -32.36672530921233], [115.96656222999665, -32.36672530921233], [115.90410905434761, -32.49580085924758], [115.60851862018583,
 -32.49580085924758], [115.67097179583487, -32.36672530921233]]]]}, "type": "Feature", "name": "Parallelogram1", "properties": {"area":
 0.000629970457642}}, 

{"geometry": {"type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [[[[116.00622565359758, -32.5791364092627],
 [116.02283522420637, -32.5791364092627], [116.02126260408991,
 -32.59706839673082], [116.00465303348112, -32.59706839673082], [116.00622565359758, -32.5791364092627]]]]}, "type": "Feature",
 "name": "Parallelogram2", "properties": {"area": 0.000629970457642} }
```

Notice the two different areas equal the same result when they should not.

The following code is how I am writing to a file.

```
import GeojsonConverter
my_geojson_string = GeojsonConverter2.convert_to_geojson(geojson_list)
name = "test"
try:
    name = name[:-4] #subtract .csv from name to add a character onto the end of the file name. Eg. zzza.csv, not zzz.csva
    with open("./datafiles/" + name + "JSON" + ".geojson", 'w') as jsondata: #Save json data into nameJSON.geojson
        try:
            print ""
            print ("Writing json file: " + name + "JSON" + ".geojson")
            jsondata.write(my_geojson_string)
        except:
            print "Error writing to file. FN: write to file"
            sys.exit()
except:
    print "Error opening file. FN: geojson output"
```

Where am I going wrong?

edit:

changed the last bit of the converter code to this

```
for d in my_list:
        coord_list = d["coordinates"]
        coord_list.append(d["coordinates"][0])
        name = d["name"]
        area_list = d["area"]

        for key in d:
            if (key is not "name") and (key is not "coordinates") and (key is not "area"):
                property_dict[key] = d[key]
            the_geom = {"type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [[coord_list]]}
            feature = {"type": "Feature", "geometry": the_geom, "name": name, "area": area_list, "properties": property_dict, }
            feature_list.append(feature)

        feature_collection = {"type": "FeatureCollection", "features": feature_list}
```

Comment: there are a number of problems, one I see is that `float(coord[0])` doesn't actually change the value to a float, you would need to do `coord[0] = float(coord[0])` to change it.

Comment: also this: `coord_list = d["coordinates"] ; coord_list.append(d["coordinates"][0])` this would add a duplicate entry of the first item to the end of the list, is this desired?

Comment: The converted code isn't mine, and actually it did work fine about 2 hours ago, since then I havent changed anything in either code and now it doesnt work

Comment: there is no duplicate entry on the output, besides ofcourse for the area, but that shouldnt be affected by coord.list

Comment: ahh, I see, you initialize `property_dict` outside of the for loop so it is reused for both entries in the list, just initialize it inside the `for d in my_list:` and it will be used separately for each.

Comment: I think i tried that before with the same result, hang on ill do it again

Comment: Ok i just edited the post at the bottom to show the change I made, still getting the same result

Comment: close the json file and reopen after running the script, notepad or what ever you are using to look at the json isn't reloading it after the change, your output does not match he result of `print(convert_to_geojson(geojson_list))`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113826/discussion-between-user6240030-and-tadhg-mcdonald-jensen).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are having a problem caused by variable reuse.

Every run through the `for d in mylist:` modifies `property_dict`, which then gets added to the `feature_list`. The next time through the loop, you modify the **same `property_dict`**, which overwrites the previous data. Moveing the `property_dict = {}` into the outer loop will fix this problem.